# VsCode crtdbg.h not found, how to fix?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, crtdbg.h

Trying to check memory leak tool but Vscode doesn't recognize `#include <crtdbg.h>`.

### Here is the code:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *word = "this still relevant.";
    char *mem = (char *)malloc(sizeof(word));
    strcpy(mem, word);
    printf("%s", mem);
    system("pause");
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

### The compile error:

```
source.c:4:10: fatal error: crtdbg.h: No such file or directory
#include <crtdbg.h>
```

> ### How do I properly include crtdbg.h?

PS: I'm using MinGW compiler, everything works except that.

EDIT 1: The solution of that other post doesn't work. If I use the suggested code this appear.

```
source.c:24:5: error: '_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks' was not declared in this scope
     _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
```

EDIT 2: Does anyone uses VsCode with MinGW?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get crtdbg.h file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685202/how-do-i-get-crtdbg-h-file)

Comment: it doesnt work that answer

Comment: `source.c:24:5: error: '_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks' was not declared in this scope
     _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();` thats what appear when used the post answer

Comment: I got other way can you check if it work for you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286935/mysql-c-api-compilation-error-crtdbg-h-not-found

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes So i cant check memory leak with MinGW?

Comment: https://www.cryengine.com/community_archive/viewtopic.php?f=314&t=73533

Comment: I just upper vote I hope someone can know what to do with it, I was searching on google about it but not a solution yet

Answer (score 1):

I think that VSCODE couldn't access to header file, crtdbg.h , Pease test a simple following way. Maybe it solved your problem:

1- Run as administrator Developer Command prompt for VS2019. I emphasized run as administrator no run.

2- Type Code .

3- Open project folder.

4- Happy coding and enjoy it.